# Relative Positioning in Responsive Designs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a responsive site with a fixed header and navbar and a rotating banner on the homepage. The banner is made using some javascript and css position values. So the header, navbar and rotating banners work fine but because the banners have width:100% and height:auto attributes they obviously expand and contract based on the window size or device. When I try to add content below I don't know what to do in order to keep it snug under the banner when I need to use position:absolute or relative and a top value for the content to appear. I've tired using a % but that doesn't seem to work.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3cg740sn/)

```
.header {
height:74px;
width:100%;
}

.navbar {
height:24px;
width:100%;
}

#banners {
position:relative;
}

#banners img {
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
top:98px;
width:100%;
height:auto;
}

#banners img.active {
z-index:3;
}

<div class="header"></div>
<div class="navbar"></div>

<div id="banners">
<img src="images/banner1.jpg" class="active" />
<img src="images/banner2.jpg" />
<img src="images/banner3.jpg" />
</div>

<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using bootstrap? it's great for getting responsive websites finished quickly.

Comment: Can you include a running example via stack snippets or jsfiddle? Your question is currently very broad and it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @CarrieKendall I have set up an example in JS Fiddle I hope it makes more sense now. See here http://jsfiddle.net/3cg740sn/